# Get object type thats randomly chosen from Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, object

I have a NSArray that is filled with different types of objects. Lets say one is a NSDictionary and another is NSData.
How would I randomly chose a object from this array and then check what kind of object it is.
So if it a NSDictionary, I will do method A.
Or if it is NSData, I will do method B.

How would I put this into code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Translated to Objective-C

```
 id obj = [array methodThatReturnsARandomObject];
 if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    a();
 } else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:obj]
 }
```

Or you can do

```
 NSObject *obj = [array methodThatReturnsARandomObject];
 if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    a();
 } else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)obj]
 }
```

Does not really matter.

Comment: One question. So in method B, say I am converting the NSData to a UIImage, how would I do that? I tried using the variable obj but it seems to throw a warning.

Comment: Did you try [UIImage imageWithData:obj]?

Comment: Yes I get Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSObject' to parameter of type 'NSData'

Comment: I get that warning when I do this: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:obj];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:image];

Comment: Ah yeah, the `imageWithData:` argument must to be `NSData` or inherited from `NSData`. Use `id` as type to skip compile time check or use an explicit cast. Updated my example code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a random number generator that will get a number that is between 0 and the last index of your array.  Then once you get the object you can use the isKindOfClass or isMemberOfClass method on the object that is returned from the array.